# Possibles to draw route in MapView

Tags: android, location, android-mapview, direction

I'm trying to do a route in MapView, I research and just find ways I need to draw lines like this: http://androidpallikoodam.wordpress.com/2012/04/04/draw-google-driving-directions-in-mapview-overlay/ , I try use this but doesn't work very well, google send me just few points so when I draw route stay wrong (or have anyway can I request more points to Google?).

I'm thinking and have anyway can I load MapView with different URL, like http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=brighton&daddr=timbuktu because if I call a new intent with this url and put this in Map from Android, the route is displayed so if I can load my MapView with this URL, maybe work.

Other option is show entire application Maps on mine Activity, so I can put other things like buttons and labels, understand? What I'm trying to say is put one application installed on android for running in a determined area on my screen. this is possible?

anyone can help me?

Thanks.